# Why isn't eqref working?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, amsmath

I am trying to use `\eqref` as in the following, but instead of (1), I get a set of blank parentheses as the result. Could anyone help me fix the problem?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1.5in,bottom=1.5in,top=1.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}  


\[
\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
\begin{align*}
1\cdot 2+2\cdot 3+3\cdot 4+ \cdots+k\cdot(k+1)+(k+1)(k+2) &= \frac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{3}       \\
&= \frac{(k^2+3k+2)(k+3)}{3} \\
&= \frac{k^3+3k^2+3k^2+9k+2k+6}{3} \\
&= \frac{k^3+6k^2+11k+6}{3}.  
\end{align*}
\end{equation}
\]

assuming ~\eqref{eq:2} ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your document does not compile - that's the problem.

Answer (score 13):

You're not allowed to use the `equation` or `align*` environments inside a display math `\[`...`\]` context. They create these themselves. Instead, use

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
  \begin{split}
    1\cdot 2+2\cdot 3+3\cdot 4+ \cdots+k\cdot(k+1)+(k+1)(k+2) &= \frac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{3}       \\
    &= \frac{(k^2+3k+2)(k+3)}{3} \\
    &= \frac{k^3+3k^2+3k^2+9k+2k+6}{3} \\
    &= \frac{k^3+6k^2+11k+6}{3}.  
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

assuming~\eqref{eq:2} ...

\end{document}
```

The above `split` usage follows directly from an example in the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) [user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) (**Table 3.1**, p 4).

Comment: it's also worth noting that a `*` on a display math environment suppresses the equation number.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to use is `eqnarray` environment instead of `align` & `equation`. `eqnarray` is available in `amsmath` package. In that case, your code will be like :

```
\begin{eqnarray*}\label{eq:2}
 1\cdot 2+2\cdot 3+3\cdot 4+ \cdots+k\cdot(k+1)+(k+1)(k+2) &=& \frac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{3}       \\
 &=& \frac{(k^2+3k+2)(k+3)}{3} \\
 &=& \frac{k^3+3k^2+3k^2+9k+2k+6}{3} \\
 &=& \frac{k^3+6k^2+11k+6}{3}.  
\end{eqnarray*}

assuming `\eqref{eq:2}` ...
```

In above case, equation number will not be visible beside the equation. You can put the equation number on selective lines by using `\nonumber` for the lines for which you don't want numbering. Suppose I want numbering only in the first & last line of the equation with equation refernce, then I will use this code :

```
\begin{eqnarray}
 1\cdot 2+2\cdot 3+3\cdot 4+ \cdots+k\cdot(k+1)+(k+1)(k+2) &=& \frac{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}{3} \label{eq:1}     \\
 &=& \frac{(k^2+3k+2)(k+3)}{3} \nonumber \\
 &=& \frac{k^3+3k^2+3k^2+9k+2k+6}{3} \nonumber \\
 &=& \frac{k^3+6k^2+11k+6}{3}. \label{eq:2}
\end{eqnarray}

assuming `\eqref{eq:1}` and `\eqref{eq:2}`...
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. `eqnarray` should in general not be used at all, see https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103madsen.pdf. And it is not actually defined by `amsmath`, but by LaTeX itself.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I always used eqnarray & never got a single problem. But thanks for the link...will take care next time.

Comment: @AvinashAnand `eqnarray` compiles fine, but looks inconsistent with the rest of the math envs + has other problems.